# Trigger to merge data from 2 tables in one new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger in SQL Server. Trigger flow would be like this: When there is new row in Table1, look for Table1.ID=Table2.ItemID, and insert data with matching ID to new table. But in one row.

Tables look like this:

[image: Tables structure]

So lets say that row with ID of 3 in Table1 is new row. The trigger would then merge data from both tables (where Table1.ID=Table2.ItemID) and insert this new row in new table like this:

[image: Output from trigger]

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you do this is your work out the queries you need to get the correct data, and convert them into insert/update/merge statements. Then you check the documentation on the syntax for a trigger, you write one, and if you get stuck somewhere along the way, you ask a question. What you don't do is ask us to do it all for you.

Comment: Why would you need this implementation - if you already have your data in these two tables, just create a view that joins them. Duplicating the data creates redundancy and discrepancies when someone updates one and not the other.

Comment: @Stu Because I need data like in example I posted, in one row.  Data is inserted to this tables through an app(PowerApps), and once inserted, it cant be updated. And i would like to also have data in one row (from multiple rows in Table2) because at the end there is some accounting program, which only accepts one row at a time.

Comment: A view will give you exactly that without storing the data again.

Comment: Problem is that I need to have 2 rows that have Table1.ID=Table2.ItemID in the same row in View or new table. If you look again in my second screenshot, there are actualy both values in one cell for rows that are from Table2. And they are comma delimited.

Comment: Does this really needs to be saved in a separate table ? A simple query can create a result set with all you need. You could also put this query in a view if you like

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_name
ON table1  
AFTER insert  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT into table3 (column1, column2, column3) 
        SELECT column1, column2, column3
        FROM inserted t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.ItemId; 
END
```